# Monitoramento Ping .BAT

Tags: batch, bat, ping

Galera perdão sou completamente leigo.
Preciso criar um arquivo . Bat que após inserção de um IP. Ele monitore o ping e emita um log caso o equipamento pare de responder com data e hora em um aquivo TXT. Podem me ajudar.